# Elasticsearch 6.4 scripted_metric aggregation Bad performance against ElasticSearch 5.1

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-6, elasticsearch-painless

I have 2 clusters of ElasticSearch:

- **old** 3 nodes(master+data)

  - ElasticSearch: 5.1.2
  - java : openjdk version "1.8.0_111"
  - -Xms12g -Xmx12g
- **new** 6 nodes(3 master + 3 data) with much better hardware (cpu/ram/hdd)

  - ElasticSearch: 6.4
  - java : openjdk version "1.8.0_181"
  - -Xms32766m -Xmx32766m

In both clusters I have an small index (about 12M docs) with same properties and  information in both clusters. And there is a search request which is using [**scripted_metric**](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html) aggregation with **painless** scripts (init/map/combine/reduce). 
And my problem is that in **old** cluster this search request works much faster than in **new** one.

I profiled request on both clusters and saw that most of time request spent in **collect** phase of **script_metric** aggreagtion, which I suppose means that map script executed longer. But I can't understand what is the reason of this slow execution same request on the same dataset. May be there are some properties shoud be set for Elastic 6.4 to enable some performance boost which was default before?

Comment: I see you have set your memory around 32Gb on the new cluster. Are you sure you are not crossing the 32G RAM limit recommendations? See here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/heap-sizing.html#compressed_oops  and https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/heap-sizing.html#_just_how_far_under_32gb_should_i_set_the_jvm

Comment: No, I'm sure that this is not reason. I've found yesterday that there is an issue with script_metric  aggregation. [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/33593)